# How to insert KeyPoints in MatOfKeyPoints

Tags: java, opencv, computer-vision, keypoint

How do I build up a `MatOfKeyPoint` correctly?

My code so far is:

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

String sourcePath = path;
Features2d features2d = new Features2d();
Mat srcImgMat = Highgui.imread(sourcePath);
MatOfKeyPoint mat = new MatOfKeyPoint(srcImgMat);
```

Now I have some `KeyPoint`s that I create and its position.

```
KeyPoint tempKeypoint = new KeyPoint();
```

But I can't insert them in the `mat` because the methode `put` doesn't support such type. What can I do?

Comment: `new MatOfKeyPoint(srcImgMat);`  pixels != keypoints . if you want to detect keypoints, you have to use a Features2d object, similar to [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.11/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html#feature-detection)

Comment: I want each pixel to be a keypoint!

Comment: So i don't want to detect keypoints. I want to create keypoints by myself and put the mit a matOfKeyPoint for descriptor calculation